# Promise can't complete the calculation

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a pretty easy formula which does not work inside Promise. Problem is following - whatever I put for parameters a and b, I always get failure, even though its clearly more thank 0. I am pretty sure that I am missing something but I can't understand what exactly, because with other formula it works (maybe I cannot call the function inside the Promise? in that case what would be the other way?). Sorry for noob question, Im new to it

```
const pidr = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const result = (a, b) => (a + b) ** 2
    result(5, 6)

    if (result > 0) {
      resolve()
    } else {
      reject()
    }
  })

  .then(() => console.log('Success'))
  .catch(() => console.error('Failure'))
```

Comment: you compare the *function* `result` with `0`, not the result of the function call `result(5, 6)`

Comment: `const fn = (a, b) => (a + b) ** 2` then `let result = fn(5, 6)`.

Comment: Are you just experimenting here, as a Promise in your code provides absolutely nothing apart from wasting CPU cycles.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create variable and set result of function execution. See below:

```
  const pidr = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const result = (a, b) => (a + b) ** 2

    const res = result(5, 6)

    if (res > 0) {
      resolve()
    } else {
      reject()
    }
  })

  .then(() => console.log('Success'))
  .catch(() => console.error('Failure'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
result(5, 6);
```

calls the function, but does not save the returned value. You then compare `result` (which is a function) to 0, and that doesn't make sense.

Instead:

```
const answer = result(5, 6);

if (answer > 0) {
  resolve()
} else {
  reject()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`result` is a function and it doesn't have to be, but if you want it to be a function you can call it inside of your `if`, like so:

```
const pidr = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const result = (a, b) => (a + b) ** 2

    if (result(5, 6) > 0) {
      resolve()
    } else {
      reject()
    }
  })

  .then(() => console.log('Success'))
  .catch(() => console.error('Failure'))
```